# DataGridView: c# generic UserDeletingRow for multiple grids on same form

Tags: c#, datagridview

I have several dgvs on a single form. They all have bound data source.
They all need to have the ability to "soft" delete rows (not really delete them, but mark the row for deletion and hide it on the grid).  The delete will happen at a later date.

I do have a filter on the on the grid: `hiatusBindingSource.Filter = "IsDeleted = false";` 
But I am not sure how to apply the filter after I set the "delete" flag so I came up with the following code to handle a specific dgv.

I want to just have one generic sub to handle all of the dgvs. (I have multiple forms with the same issue.)

```
private void dgvHiatus_UserDeletingRow(object sender, DataGridViewRowCancelEventArgs e)
{
    e.Cancel = true;
    hiatusBindingSource.SuspendBinding();
    e.Row.Visible = false;
    hiatusBindingSource.ResumeBinding();
    ((Hiatus)e.Row.DataBoundItem).IsDeleted = true;
    SetFormMode(Globals.FormStatusMode.Save);
}
```

TIA

Comment: This would be easy if your classes derive from a common base class where the IsDeleted property is common to all derived classes

Comment: DOH!  Of course. I have a base class. Call it "basex" for now. Is there a better method of setting "IsDeleted" that what I have ?  Thanks Steve

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If all of your DataGridView are bounded using a BindingSouce and the classes used as DataSource for the BindingSource derive a common base class that has defined the IsDeleted property then I suppose you could make just one event handler for all your DataGrid with code like this

```
private void common_dgv_DeletingRow(object sender, DataGridViewRowCancelEventArgs e)
{
    e.Cancel = true;
    DataGridView dgv = sender as DataGridView;
    BindingSource bs = dgv.DataSource as BindingSource;
    bs.SuspendBinding();
    e.Row.Visible = false;
    bs.ResumeBinding();
    ((basex)e.Row.DataBoundItem).IsDeleted = true;
    SetFormMode(Globals.FormStatusMode.Save);
}
```

Of course I am not able to test it but you could comment here if you have any difficulty.

Comment: Great!!!! it worked. I had to make 1 adjustment:
BindingSource bs = (BindingSource)dgv.DataSource;

One more question --> since I have a filter on the BindingSource, 
hiatusBindingSource.Filter = "IsDeleted = false";

is there another method that I can use to hide the row by having the filter apply after I set "IsDeleted = true;" ?

Thanks for the help. I really appreciate it.